# SqlCommand Method Error while executing INSERT query in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am working on WPF application in C#. Database is SQL Server 2008. I have a table "Employee" in database, I need to insert a row in it. I have successfully connected with database, but when I tried to execute this line:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
```

This errors comes up: **The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(String, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments.**
 
Here is my code:

```
private void addbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //FUNCTION TO ADD NEW EMPLOYEE RECORD IN DATABASE
        try
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=AZEEMPC;" + "Initial Catalog=IEPL_Attendance_DB;";
            conn.Open();
            cmdText = "INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('" + strCurrentString + "','" + emp_name.Text + "')";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
            data_ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            data = new DataSet();
            data_ad.Fill(data);
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conn` needs to be of type `SqlConnection` - can you confirm that it is?

```
SqlConnection conn;
```

Because it's a native SQL Server connection, you don't need to pass the driver name in the connection string.

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Server=AZEEMPC;Database=IEPL_Attendance_DB;Trusted_Connection=true;";
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out! I just noticed that I declared conn as:
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
Now I changed it as:
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
but after changing this, my application does not connect to database!!
It shows exception that 'Login failed for User". '
I have configured sql server in windows authentication mode.

Comment: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to include the trusted_connection=true in the connection string to enable a trusted Windows Authentication connection.